# Relationship between density function

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

[image: Question]

Could someone help me on this question. I'm not entirely sure how to relate the two different density functions to each other.

Comment: Write down the CDF and of $Y=e^{x}$ and differentiate.

Comment: To find the density function of $Y$, first find the CDF of $Y$ by evaluating $P(Y\le y)=P(e^X\le y)$

Answer (score 2):

First let's find $F_Y(y)$ with the definition

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[e^X\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X\leq log(y)]=F_X(log(y))$$

Now let's calculate its derivative to get the requested density

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(log(y))\cdot \frac{1}{y}\mathbb{1}_{(e;e^2)}(y)$$

...that is (a)